# iOS - App Icons Support error with Phonegap Build Project with different supported versions of iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, build, icons, application-loader

I'm having trouble publishing my .ipa file
I generated through Phonegap Build however I get the following message from the Application Loader:

"Missing required ico file ... The bundle does not contain an app icon for Iphone ... 120 x 120 pixel in format for ios version> = 7" "

Where am I going wrong?

Follow my config.xml above

```
<icon src="ic_launcher.png" />
<icon height="72" src="ic_launcher.png" width="72" />
<icon height="48" src="ic_launcher.png" width="48" />
<icon height="36" src="ic_launcher.png" width="36" />
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000"/>
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="blackopaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />    
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="~3.1.5" />
<platform name="ios">
    <!-- iPhone 6 / 6+ -->
    <icon src="icon-60@3x.png" platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="icon-60.png" platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="icon-60@2x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="Icon-60x60@1x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="Icon-60x60@2x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="Icon-60x60@3x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="icon-76.png" platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="icon-76@2x.png" platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
    <icon src="icon-83.5@2x.png" platform="ios" width="167" height="167" />
    <!-- Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="icon-small.png" platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="icon-small@2x.png" platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
    <icon src="icon-small@3x.png" platform="ios" width="87" height="87" />
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="icon-40.png" platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="icon-40@2x.png" platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
    <icon src="icon-40@3x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
</platform>
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="*://*.googleapis.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*.google.com" />
<access origin="*.googleapis.com" />
<access origin="*.gstatic.com" />
<access origin="*.googleusercontent.com" />
<access origin="google.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="googleapis.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="gstatic.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="googleusercontent.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
<access origin="https://example.com" />
<access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin=".*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. Follow solution below:

```
    <platform name="ios">
    <icon height="57"  platform="ios"  src="icon.png"           width="57" />
    <icon height="114" platform="ios"  src="icon-2x.png"        width="114" />
    <icon height="40"  platform="ios"  src="icon-40.png"        width="40" />
    <icon height="80"  platform="ios"  src="icon-40-2x.png"     width="80" />
    <icon height="50"  platform="ios"  src="icon-50.png"        width="50" />
    <icon height="100" platform="ios"  src="icon-50-2x.png"     width="100" />
    <icon height="60"  platform="ios"  src="icon-60.png"        width="60" />
    <icon height="120" platform="ios"  src="icon-60-2x.png"     width="120" />
    <icon height="180" platform="ios"  src="icon-60-3x.png"     width="180" />
    <icon height="72"  platform="ios"  src="icon-72.png"        width="72" />
    <icon height="144" platform="ios"  src="icon-72-2x.png"     width="144" />
    <icon height="76"  platform="ios"  src="icon-76.png"        width="76" />
    <icon height="152" platform="ios"  src="icon-76-2x.png"     width="152" />
    <icon height="29"  platform="ios"  src="icon-small.png"     width="29" />
    <icon height="58"  platform="ios"  src="icon-small-2x.png"  width="58" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not have added icon files for all OS versions (supported in your project).

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/) is details of all size of icons, you should add.

List of required icons sizes (Consider support for different device for you like iPad, iPod, iPhone, Watch, iTune, spotlight  or CarPlay)

```
Icon-Small.png - 29x29 
Icon-Small@2x.png - 58x58 
Icon-Small@3x.png - 87x87 
Icon-40.png - 40x40 
Icon-40@2x.png - 80x80 
Icon-40@3x.png - 120x120 
Icon-60@2x.png - 120x120 
Icon-60@3x.png - 180x180 
Icon-76.png - 76x76 
Icon-76@2x.png - 152x152 
Icon-120.png - 120x120
```